# Expected Number of steps

Tags: probability, self-study, random-walk

At each stage a person either moves one step to the right with probability 0.6 or one step to the left with probability 0.4.Assuming the direction of each step is independent

I want to find the expected number of steps it takes a person to be r steps to the right of where she began.

Answer:-15r steps. Is this right answer? If wrong, what would be correct answer?

Comment: Use a random variable with binomial distribution where the outcome $1$ stands for "step to the right". Then you can use the fact that the sum of independent binomially distributed random variables again follows a binomial distribution.

Comment: Sorry, was to slow in editing my previous comment which is not true! Next try from my side: Consider the r.v. $X_n$ which gives the position after $n$ steps. $n$ can be written as $n=k+(n-k)$ with $k$ equal to the number of steps to the right. The position is thus $X_n=k-(n-k)=2k-n$. What can be said about the distribution of $X_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be 5 r.

The simple explanation is that for every 10 steps, the person takes (on average) 6 steps right and 4 steps left.  Thus he moves (on average) 2 steps right / 10 steps or 1 step right per 5 steps.

Comment: I was also thinking about the same answer.However,thanks.